# Xamarin Community Toolkit TabView height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabview, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a view that has images and texts at the top. At the bottom I have a TabView with different TabViewItems. Each TabViewItem has a different height since each one has different content.

I want the height of the TabView to match the height of the TabViewItem that is taller, but I can't do it.

If I don't specify the TabContentHeight property, only the TabView headers are shown and if I put a size to it, the content of the TabViewItems is cut off.
What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Could you post your xaml code please? "different content" means label length or icon size or sth else?

Comment: I have 4 TabViewItems. One has a gallery with several images (you can have only 1 or several). Another TabViewItem has text, it can be little or a lot with many lines and other similar TabViewItems. Everyone can grow in content, therefore I need the TabView to grow as well.

Comment: You can try setting TabStripHeight, it should help

Comment: try set the HeightRequest on xct:TabView instead of TabContentHeight

Answer (score 1):

Check this articles for TabView if you want bottom tabs UI.

1. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-community-toolkit-tabview/
2. https://www.sharpnado.com/pure-xamarin-forms-tabs/

But the what you mentioned that you want to grow tab size according to content than I think you do not need tabview, you have to create your own CustomView for that.

You can also use Syncfusion control for this: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11007/how-to-reduce-or-increase-the-tab-header-height-in-xamarin-forms-sftabview

TabView just provide UI with:

- Icon and Label
- Only Icon
- Only Text

And its size is fixed.

You can change its background color for active/inactive state.

Answer (score 0):

> If I don't specify the TabContentHeight property, only the TabView headers are shown and if I put a size to it, the content of the TabViewItems is cut off. What would be the correct way to do it?

Maybe you can try to add `ScrollView` in `TabViewItem` to contain content.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="waterfront.jpg" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="this is test" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <xct:TabView
            TabContentBackgroundColor="Yellow"
            TabIndicatorColor="Yellow"
            TabStripBackgroundColor="Blue"
            TabStripHeight="60"
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom">

            <xct:TabViewItem
                FontSize="12"
                Icon="triangle.png"
                Text="Tab 1"
                TextColor="White"
                TextColorSelected="Yellow">
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">

                        <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Text="TabContent1"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Image  Source="waterfront.jpg" />
                        <Image  Source="internet.png" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </xct:TabViewItem>

            <xct:TabViewItem
                FontSize="12"
                Icon="circle.png"
                Text="Tab 2"
                TextColor="White"
                TextColorSelected="Yellow">
                <Grid>
                    <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="TabContent2"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </xct:TabViewItem>
        </xct:TabView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the only solution I have found. I have also researched on the painting events but I cannot change the size of the TabView at runtime, although I can determine the size of the largest TabViewItem and apply it to the TabContentHeight property it does not change the size.

Comment: In case it is not clear, I add this link. https://www.iherb.com/pr/country-life-natural-omega-3-1-000-mg-300-softgels/9707
The effect I want to achieve is that of this website, which also works the same in its APP version.
Each product has a Tab with different TabItems and the tab always occupies the entire screen. There is not a Scroll within each tab.

Comment: @Rocoso It looks different from tabview, maybe you can try to create custom dialog when press label.

Comment: The mobile version of Iherb (open the web with the Chorme simulating a mobile phone) and the APP has a TabView at the bottom with different pages (Overview, Details, Reviews ...)
Each product has those TabItems with different sizes, depending on the product, the Tabs are adjusted in height.
I want to get similar functionality with the TabView but I can't.

Comment: @Rocoso Maybe you can try to search some third party to achieve it.